# Json response based on parameter in webapi

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

My API controller method is

```
public IQueryable<Team> GetTeam([FromUri] string include = "")
{
     return from c in db.Team select new Team { id = c.TeamID, name = c.teamName, logo = "", social = new Map.Social { facebook = "", twitter = "" } };
}
```

the response from the above method is

```
[{"id":1,"name":"example","logo":"","social":{"twitter":"","facebook":""}}]
```

The issue is that the above response should be created if the method accepts *"social"* as the `include` parameter.

If the `include` parameter is `null` the response should be

```
[{"id":1,"name":"example","logo":""}]
```

How should I change the code above to make that happen?

The classes used:

```
public class Team
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string logo { get; set; }
   public Social social { get; set; }
}

public class Social
{
   public string twitter { get; set; }
   public string facebook { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this really what you want? I'd return the same structure - it's the consumer responsibility to handle empty collections or nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of your question explains what needs to be programmed.

A simplified example would be

```
public IQueryable<Team> GetTeam([FromUri] string include = "") {

    //If the include parameter is null the response should be 
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(include) {
        return from c in db.Team select new Team { id = c.TeamID, name = c.teamName, logo = ""};
    }

     return from c in db.Team select new Team { id = c.TeamID, name = c.teamName, logo = "", social = new Map.Social { facebook = "", twitter = "" } };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is close enough but it returns [{"id":1,"name":"example","logo":"","social":null}] i wish i could declate nullable of a class :)

Comment: @OrElse, Update json formatter on startup to exclude null properties. That or you can also create an anonymous type without that  property. both options will work

Comment: You rock! This one made the magic [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]

Comment: @OrElse, perfect. I forgot about using that attribute. Glad you got it to work. Happy Coding!!!